# Failed deploy react-native application

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I deploy release build of my application according docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html. I haven't any problems with deploying debug build. But with release build I got this error message: `Task 'installReleaseDebug' not found in root project`

I launch deploying my app using command `react-native run-android --variant=release` (this command starts `installDebugRelease` gradle task)

My build.gradle settings:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.keystore")
            storePassword "myKeyStorePassword"
            keyAlias "my-key-alias"
            keyPassword "myKeyPassword"
        }
    }
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

After running command `gradlew tasks` i found `installRelease` instead of `installDebugRelease`.

Comment: Can you check if you are editing the correct file which is located in 'android/app/build.gradle'? (Not the one in 'android/build.gradle')

Comment: @max23_, I edit exactly 'android/app/build.gradle' according docs.

Comment: Weird, it is working fine for me. Running `react-native run-android --variant=release` should run installRelease unless you run `react-native run-android --variant=debugRelease` then you will get the invalid task error. You are on which version of React Native?

Comment: @max23_, I've tried with 0.39 and 0.38 versions

Comment: 'Debug' is automatically added to the end of task name.

Comment: Try delete the 'node_modules' folder and run `npm install` to reinstall all the node modules. Then, run `react-native run-android --variant=release` again.

Comment: @max23_, unfortunately, it doesn't help. If I run manually `gradlew installRelease` it will be the same result?

Comment: Yup, I guess probably you need to run `cd android && gradlew installRelease` in your project folder. It is the same as running `react-native run-android --variant=release`.

Comment: You are still getting 'installReleaseDebug' when you run `react-native run-android --variant=release` after trying my last suggestion?

Comment: @max23_, yes, after your last suggestion I have same result. But `gradlew installRelease` works properly.